# How to stop ivy-switch-buffer from trying to connect

Tags: tramp, ssh, ivy, recentf, history

I'm using `ivy-use-virtual-buffers` to see both currently and recently visited buffers in [Swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.org)'s `ivy-switch-buffer` and it worked great until last month when I opened distant files via ssh/Tramp.

Ever since, `ivy-switch-buffer` errors, see below.

Questions

- How exactly is `ivy-ignore-buffers` (see config below) supposed to work ? On full buffer names (w/ path)?
- How is ivy-switch-buffer trying to connect? I can see in the error buffer that is uses some username that I don't use anymore to connect... Where are those connection details stored?
- Why is `ivy-switch-buffer` trying to connect in the first place ? `counsel-recentf` does not do that, the distant buffers are sitting quietly in the list, and when selected, Emacs connects (using the right SSH credentials / aliases / keys) and opens the file.

Here is my configuration:

```
(use-package swiper
  :ensure try
  :bind
  (([f4] . ivy-switch-buffer)
   ([(control c) (f)] . counsel-ag)
   ([(control c) (g)] . counsel-git)
   ([(control c) (j)] . counsel-git-grep)
   ([(control c) (l)] . counsel-locate)
   ([(control d)] . swiper-ag)
   ([(control f)] . swiper)
   ([(control h) (control f)] . counsel-describe-function)
   ([(control h) (control v)] . counsel-describe-variable)
   ([(control o)] . counsel-find-file)
   ([(control shift o)] . counsel-recentf)
   ([f9] . counsel-rhythmbox)
   :map ivy-minibuffer-map
   ([(control f)] . ivy-yank-word)
   :map read-expression-map
   ([(control r)] . counsel-expression-history))
  :config
  (progn
    (define-key
      ivy-switch-buffer-map
      [(control w)]
      (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (ivy-set-action 'kill-buffer)
        (ivy-done))))
  :init
  (setq  ivy-use-virtual-buffers t
         ivy-ignore-buffers '("^\\/ssh" ; doesn't seem to work
                              "\\` "
                              "\\`\\*")
         ivy-display-style 'fancy
         ivy-count-format "(%d/%d) "
         ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil
         ivy-extra-directories nil))
```

And the errors:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for weird_username@myserver.com using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh -l weird_username  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none myserver.com’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
Tramp failed to connect.  If this happens repeatedly, try
    ‘M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
Tramp: Opening connection for weird_username@myserver.com using ssh...failed
tramp-file-name-handler: Tramp failed to connect.  If this happens repeatedly, try
    ‘M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection’
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found this file :

```
# cat ~/.emacs.d/tramp
;; -*- emacs-lisp -*- <21/02/05 12:48:54 /home/xxxxxx/.emacs.d/tramp>
;; Tramp connection history.  Don't change this file.
;; You can delete it, forcing Tramp to reapply the checks.

(((tramp-file-name "ssh" nil nil "sbc" nil nil nil)
  nil)
 ((tramp-file-name "ssh" "weird_username" nil "myserver.com" nil nil nil)
  nil))
```

I did what it says on the tin and deleted it. Then I removed all mentions of `weird_username` and `myserver.com` in both `~/.emacs.d/history` and `~/.emacs.d/recentf`, and now `ivy-switch-buffer` works ; Phew.